# Cannot edit the data in a cell of a datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have some problems with the datagridview in c#. Now the EditMode property of it is EditOnKeystrokeOrF2 and the Readonly property is false. And the dataSourse of it is binded to a list. I double clicked on one cell(for example, the data is 40), then I could edit it(change it to 60). But if I press enter, the data of the cell is not updated, it is still 40. I'm wondering the reason. Then I tried the CellEndEdit event, and added a Breakpoint here.

```
 private void dataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
     dataGridView.RefreshEdit();
     if (e.ColumnIndex==0)
     {
         double key = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
     }
 }
```

Then I run the program, double click on a cell in the first column, changed it, pressed enter. And it came to the breakpoint, and the data i got is still the old one. Anyone knows the reason? How can I edit it by clicking on it? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: you need to share more code. i have made a simple example and it worked for me so something else is wrong